# what is the logic of this code in SAS Macros?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
%let x = 15;


  %macro test;
        %let x = 10;
        %put x inside macro test = &x;
    %mend test;

    %test;

    %put x outside the macro test =&x;
    %put x inside the macro test =&x;
```

i need to know what is value of test outside the macro defination?

Comment: what i know is that , within the macro defination macros are saved in local symbol table . variable X is created using %let statement inside the macro defination test is local in nature. I am not sure why it's showing global nature when i am calling it outside macro defination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a macro variable is defined in the global scope, i.e. your `%LET X = 15;`, then any changes within a macro to that macro variable affect the global value, unless you explicitly override it within the macro using `%LOCAL X;`.

```
%let x = 15; /* Global X = 15 */

%macro test;
   %let x = 10; /* Global X = 10 */
   %put x inside macro test = &x; /* 10 */
%mend test;
%test;

%put x outside the macro test =&x; /* 10 */
```

But with `%LOCAL`

```
%let x = 15; /* Global X = 15 */

%macro test;
   %local x;
   %let x = 10; /* Local X = 10 */
   %put x inside macro test = &x; /* 10 */
%mend test;
%test;

%put x outside the macro test =&x; /* 15 */
```

Comment: what if :     
%macro test1;
 %local value2;
 data _null_;
  call symput ('value1','20');
 run;

 %let value2=100;
%mend test1;

%test1;

%put A = &value1 and B=&value2;

Comment: In other words, inside macros, always ensure you either define your macro variables as either `local` or `global` to avoid bugs.